# XUnit Test Constructor dependence injection with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, xunit2

I am implementing Xunit with Autofac, I could make it work by below code:

```
using (var scoped = DbFixture.Container.Resolve<UserReponsitory>())
{
    var result = (scoped.GetAll()).ToList().Count();
    Assert.Equal(2, result);
}
```

But I want to inject UserReponsitory to test method instead of using `DbFixture.Container.Resolve`. Is it possible to make below code work?
UnitTest1.cs

```
namespace XUnitTestPro
{
    public class UnitTest1:IClassFixture<DbFixture>
    {
        private IUserReponsitory _userReponsitory;
        public UnitTest1(IUserReponsitory userReponsitory)
        {
            _userReponsitory = userReponsitory;
        }
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            //using (var scoped = DbFixture.Container.Resolve<UserReponsitory>())
            //{
            //    var result = (scoped.GetAll()).ToList().Count();
            //    Assert.Equal(2, result);
            //}
            var result = _userReponsitory.GetAll().ToList().Count();
            Assert.Equal(2, result);
        }
    }
}
```

DbFixture.cs

```
namespace XUnitTestPro
{
    public class DbFixture
    {
        public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        public DbFixture()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>().UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EFProject;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true").Options;
            UserContext context = new UserContext(option);
            builder.RegisterInstance(context).As<UserContext>();

            builder.RegisterType<UserReponsitory>().AsSelf().As<IUserReponsitory>();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DbFixture).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            Container = builder.Build();

        }
    }
}
```

At present, I got below error, it seems to be related with `IClassFixture<DbFixture>` and `public UnitTest1(IUserReponsitory userReponsitory)` are different.

> Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching
> fixture data: IUserReponsitory userReponsitory

Is there any way to achieve below code without call `DbFixture.Container.Resolve` which is similar to inject MVC Controller?

```
public UnitTest1(IUserReponsitory userReponsitory)
{
    _userReponsitory = userReponsitory;
}
```

In other words, how could I dependence inject Unit Test class?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection support in xUnit is kinda limited.

When you implement `IClassFixture<DbFixture>` interface, then xUnit expects **one `DbFixture` parameter** in it's constructor, and the type of the parameter depends on `T` in `IClassFixture<T>`.

That being said, when you implmenent `IClassFixture<DbFixture>` your constructor must look like `public UnitTest1(DbFixture)`. But you have `IUserRepository`, so xUnit doesn't know what to inject in there.

You can also implement multiple `IClassFixture<T>` types, but you can use each `T` only once per test class.

From the official [xUnit docs on shared context](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html) (`IClassFixture<T>`):

> ***Important note**: xUnit.net uses the presence of the interface IClassFixture<> to know that you want a class fixture to be created and cleaned up. It will do this whether you take the instance of the class as a constructor argument or not. Simiarly, if you add the constructor argument but forget to add the interface, xUnit.net will let you know that it does not know how to satisfy the constructor argument.*

#### Update

It's still possible to use the IoC container resolve it, just not with constructor injection.

```
public class DbFixture
{
    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public DbFixture()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UserContext>().UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EFProject;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true").Options;
        UserContext context = new UserContext(option);
        builder.RegisterInstance(context).As<UserContext>();

        builder.RegisterType<UserReponsitory>().AsSelf().As<IUserReponsitory>();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DbFixture).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        Container = builder.Build();
    }
}

public class UnitTest1:IClassFixture<DbFixture>
{
    private IUserReponsitory _userReponsitory;
    public UnitTest1(DbFixture fixture)
    {
        // resolve it here
        _userReponsitory = fixture.Container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //using (var scoped = DbFixture.Container.Resolve<UserReponsitory>())
        //{
        //    var result = (scoped.GetAll()).ToList().Count();
        //    Assert.Equal(2, result);
        //}
        var result = _userReponsitory.GetAll().ToList().Count();
        Assert.Equal(2, result);
    }
}
```

However, the question is rather is that good way to use it? Not sure what you want to reach, but if you want do **unit** tests, then you don't have to use IoC container at all or concrete classes, just mocks and the type you are testing.

If you want do integration tests on ASP.NET Core MVC / WebApi, then you should rather use `TestServer` class which spins up the whole application with all IoC you have configured there already.

Comment: With IClassFixture, it seems I could not achieve `IUserReponsitory ` dependence injection. I change to use xunit2.ioc.autofac. But, it seems it did not work under net462. Could you help to check below post.[XUnit Test different results under netcoreapp1.1 and net462](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537944/xunit-test-different-results-under-netcoreapp1-1-and-net462)

Comment: Well you could resolve it, change `public static IContainer Container { get; set; }` to `public IContainer Container { get; set; }` (not really required, but static fields make it rather to a factory) and access the container manually via `myfixture.Container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();`. you just can't use constructor injection for it

Answer (score 0):

If you already have constructor injection enabled in your unit tests, you are nearly done.  In the constructor of your test, inject a

```
Func<Owned<UserReponsitory>>
```

e.g.

```
namespace XUnitTestPro
{
public class UnitTest1:IClassFixture<DbFixture>
{
    private Func<Owned<UserReponsitory>> _userRepositoryFactory;
    public UnitTest1(Func<Owned<UserReponsitory>> userRepositoryFactory )
    {
        _userReponsitoryFactory = userReponsitoryFactory;
    }
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //using (var scoped = DbFixture.Container.Resolve<UserReponsitory>())
        //{
        //    var result = (scoped.GetAll()).ToList().Count();
        //    Assert.Equal(2, result);
        //}

        using (var scoped = userReponsitoryFactory())
        {
            var result = (scoped.Value.GetAll()).ToList().Count();
            Assert.Equal(2, result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Func is a factory that allows you to return a Owned.  Owned is a container that allows you to dispose your object on your own (the using block)

Comment: got below error:The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: Func`1 userReponsitory

Answer (score 0):

Using autofac constructor injection with XUnit (in friendly way) is possible.

For XUnit dependency injection in general use [Xunit.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/pengweiqhca/Xunit.DependencyInjection) library. This allows you configure service registrations inside your `ConfigureHost` method.

Then you can configure your autofac container in this way:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureHost(IHostBuilder hostBuilder) =>
            hostBuilder
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder => { })
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
                {
                    //autofac registrations
                    builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
                });
    }
```

Feel free to inject `IRepository` into your test class now.

```cs
    public class SampleTests
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public SampleTests(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Loaded_data_from_injected_repository_is_not_empty()
        {
            var data = _repository.LoadSomething();
            Assert.IsNotEmpty(data);
        }
    }
```