# XUnit Test different results under netcoreapp1.1 and net462

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, xunit

I created a XUnit test projects in VS 2017, its target framework is netcoreapp1.1, and below code works correctly.

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using Xunit.Ioc.Autofac;

namespace XUnitTestProject2
{
    [UseAutofacTestFramework]
    public class MyAwesomeTests
    {
        public MyAwesomeTests()
        {
        }

        public MyAwesomeTests(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
        {
            _outputHelper = outputHelper;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void AssertThatWeDoStuff()
        {
            _outputHelper.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper;
    }
}

using Autofac;
using System.Reflection;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using Xunit.Ioc.Autofac;
using Xunit.Sdk;


[assembly: TestFramework("XUnitTestProject2.ConfigureTestFramework", "XUnitTestProject2")]
namespace XUnitTestProject2
{
    public class ConfigureTestFramework : AutofacTestFramework
    {
        private const string TestSuffixConvention = "Tests";

        public ConfigureTestFramework(IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink)
            : base(diagnosticMessageSink)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ConfigureTestFramework).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith(TestSuffixConvention));

            builder.RegisterType<TestOutputHelper>().AsSelf().As<ITestOutputHelper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // configure your container
            // e.g. builder.RegisterModule<TestOverrideModule>();

            Container = builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I change the targetframework to net462, there will not tests be found.
Did i miss anything?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to target both frameworks, use plural tag `<TargetFrameworks>net462;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>

Comment: I referenced a .net framework library, so I could not target to netcoreapp1.1

Comment: You can add conditional references if you edit the `.csproj` file by hand. If you look at [this example from AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/b258d5e0277439b2ea4d2cf3c546c97322614c74/src/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.csproj#L65-L68), references to .NET framework assemblies are conditioned by the fact that the current target framework is .NET 4.5